# C# table with column as row

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, tabular

I am wondering if it is possible to have a table in C# which allows one of the columns to appear as a row so each record is effectively two rows.

I am attempting to create a search engine for documents. I would like document properties such as document title, date created to be put into columns and also have an extract of the document in a column as well however I feel it would be more appropriate if the extract was on a new line similar to how google displays results with a page extract. I will be grateful for any advice on how this could be achieved. I am currently considering creating a jQuery component and loading it in this way unless there are any easier methods? Below is a depiction of how I imagine the table to look:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|Col 1 | col 2                 | col3         |
-----------------------------------------------
|Data  |         data          | data         |
|Contents of col4                             |
-----------------------------------------------
|Data  |         data          | data         |
|Contents of col4                             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a table in c#"? Are you talking about a database table? An HTML table? Something else?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean for display of the table for the UI - what are you currently using to display the table?

Comment: Hi sorry yeh its for the UI i've looked at both ListView and Datagrid view. I can fill the columns with my search result but i'd like to have a new line for column 4 if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Store the "extract" in it's own column in the database (each row is one "document"). Then, in your view, you can have it be displayed as it's own row in the HTML table. No need for jQuery.

Comment: would there be a way of getting user events from the html table after the user clicked on a result back into the program? all i'd need to know is which result they clicked on so the document could be displayed

Comment: @user233354 - Yes. One way would be to provide them a link to click for each row (just like normal HTML). The other would be to use jQuery (and possibly AJAX) to handle it. But that's getting beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I don't suppose you could give me an example, I'm a little stuck on how the html code could be passed back to the c# program

Comment: Just look for examples of using AJAX with the ASP.Net framework. I believe the Nerd Diner MVC sample has this for some of it's functionality.